# Is it possible to authenticate against a web service and against a proxy in the same HTTP request?

Tags: http, authentication, curl, basic-authentication

I have a service that I would like to access from cURL and browser on which is enabled LDAP Basic Auth. But this service is a backend of a proxy on which is enable another Basic Auth.

So to reach my service my request has to send two different Basic Auth headers. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to authenticate against your application and against a proxy in the same request.

### Authorization header

To authenticate against your application, use the [`Authorization`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2) HTTP header:

> [**4.2.  Authorization**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2)
>
> The `Authorization`  header field allows a user agent to authenticate
> itself with an origin server -- usually, but not necessarily, after
> receiving a `401` (Unauthorized) response.  Its value consists of
> credentials containing the authentication information of the user
> agent for the realm of the resource being requested.
>
> ```
> Authorization = credentials
> ```
>
> If a request is authenticated and a realm specified, the same
> credentials are presumed to be valid for all other requests within
> this realm (assuming that the authentication scheme itself does not
> require otherwise, such as credentials that vary according to a
> challenge value or using synchronized clocks). [...]

### Proxy-Authorization header

To authenticate against the proxy, use the [`Proxy-Authorization`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.4) HTTP header:

> [**4.4.  Proxy-Authorization**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.4)
>
> The `Proxy-Authorization` header field allows the client to identify
> itself (or its user) to a proxy that requires authentication.  Its
> value consists of credentials containing the authentication
> information of the client for the proxy and/or realm of the resource
> being requested.
>
> ```
>  Proxy-Authorization = credentials
> ```
>
> Unlike `Authorization`, the `Proxy-Authorization` header field applies
> only to the next inbound proxy that demanded authentication using the
> `Proxy-Authenticate` field.  When multiple proxies are used in a chain,
> the `Proxy-Authorization` header field is consumed by the first inbound
> proxy that was expecting to receive credentials.  A proxy MAY relay
> the credentials from the client request to the next proxy if that is
> the mechanism by which the proxies cooperatively authenticate a given
> request.

### Basic Authentication

For more details on the HTTP Basic Authentication scheme, check the [RFC 7617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617#section-2):

> [**2. The 'Basic' Authentication Scheme**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617#section-2)
>
> The Basic authentication scheme is based on the model that the client
> needs to authenticate itself with a user-id and a password for each
> protection space ("realm"). [...] The server will service the request only if it can validate
> the user-id and password for the protection space applying to the
> requested resource.
>
> [...]
>
> To receive authorization, the client
>
> 1. obtains the user-id and password from the user,
> 2. constructs the user-pass by concatenating the user-id, a single
>    colon (":") character, and the password,
> 3. encodes the user-pass into an octet sequence,
> 4. and obtains the basic-credentials by encoding this octet sequence
>    using [Base64](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-4) into a sequence of [US-ASCII
>    characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc20).
>
> [...]
>
> If the user agent wishes to send the user-id "Aladdin" and password
> "open sesame", it would use the following header field:
>
> ```
> Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
> ```
>
> [...]

---

Your cURL command line would be like:

```shell
curl -X GET \
     -H "Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==" \
     -H "Proxy-Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==" \
     "http://example.com/api"
```

---

**Important!** Please note that the name of these HTTP headers are unfortunate because they carry *authentication* data instead of *authorization* data. Anyways, these are the standard headers for sending credentials in HTTP.